Is EAS build possible without developer account and without Xcode and Android Studio?
I'm migrating an app from React Native to Expo 51. So far I've been using Expo Go to build and test the app, but now I am required to integrate Firebase Analytics into the app. The docs say this requires the use of 'React Native Firebase', which requires custom native code and cannot be used with Expo Go. One of the main reasons for the migration was to abandon Xcode and Android Studio, so I guess I will be using EAS. However, the EAS docs are not so clear to me.
If I start using EAS, will I be able to test the app without the iOS or Android simulator (XCode and Android Studio) AND without having an Apple Developer account?
I understand I would be able to download the Build Artifact and run on my device (I have an iPhone), but it seems like I need the developer account for that.
I haven't tried anything yet besides installing expo-dev-client and investigating.

As a developer using Expo for many years, I know you can do a build and, just as you said, download that build on your device from the build website, and it will work as expected. You are able to download builds for both Android (APK or AAB) and iOS.
But to make the build, you will need a developer account, as of my understanding (if you want to download it to your physical device), or else you will need a Mac and make a simulator build, as this comment explains: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/997#issuecomment-1603430682
You could read the following discussion or issue: https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/997.
I will quote one comment from there:

Apple does not allow sideloading; to install an app on a physical
iPhone, it needs to be signed with a distribution certificate that can
be generated only if you have a paid Apple account. With a free Apple
account, you can build apps signed with developer certificates, but
you need to build them from Xcode (we do not support it in eas because
it would require rebuilds every time because developer certificates
have a short expiration time).

Have a great day.

Thank you :)
I have a Mac but a bit older and Xcode is just too buggy on it...
You mentioned making a simulator build, is that possible without Xcode ?
Later we will use EAS build, but right now we are at prototyping and heavy testing so free solutions are welcomed and Expo Go is also perfect at the moment. It's only I was asked to integrate Firebase Analytics already that brings the trouble.

Yes, you can make a simulator build without Xcode.
One thing you could do is test PostHog (https://posthog.com/) in your application, which is a great analytics service, plus it contains other great products. I believe you don't need a development client to use it. But you should test whether you actually need the development client or not. I am not 100% certain of this, as I haven't personally used it but have heard much good about it.
